# wcf, duplex - связь

Tags: wcf

задача такая - создал "клиент - сервер" с дуплексной связью, когда запуская оба проекта на дебаг(это один солюшен) то дуплексная связь работает, а если я вызываю сначала серверную часть а с нее открываю клиентскую часть то выскакивает ошибка при вызове дуплексной связи

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Не удалось найти элемент конечной точки с именем "NetTcpBinding_IContractServer" и контрактом "ConnectService.IContractServer" в разделе конфигурации клиента ServiceModel. Это может быть вызвано тем, что для приложения не найден файл конфигурации или в элементе клиента не найден элемент конечной точки, соответствующий данному имени.'`

для более понятного представления сделаю скрин самого солюшена[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот app.config хоста

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ServiceVideoPlayer.Service" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
    <endpoint address="ServiceVideoPlayer" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ServiceVideoPlayer.IContractServer"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="mexBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

вот код плеера где я даю запрос серверу и жду от него ответ

```
namespace VideoPlayer
{

    public partial class MainWindow : ConnectService.IContractServerCallback
    { 

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlayButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);
            var client = new ConnectService.ContractServerClient(instanceContext, "NetTcpBinding_IContractServer");
            client.Play(true);
        }


        public void PlayBak(bool status)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(status ? "Play" : "Stop");
        }
    }
}
```

и вот еще сам контракт

```
namespace ServiceVideoPlayer
{
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IContractCallBack))]
    public interface IContractServer
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Play(bool status);
    }

    public interface IContractCallBack
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void PlayBak(bool status);
    }
}
```

ВЫЗОВ ОКНА КЛИЕНТСКОЙ ЧАСТИ

```
 private void OpenNewVideoPlayerButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var videoPlayerWindow = new VideoPlayer.MainWindow();
        videoPlayerWindow.Show();
    }
```

вот config client

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IContractServer" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8090/ServiceVideoPlayer"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IContractServer"
            contract="ConnectService.IContractServer" name="NetTcpBinding_IContractServer">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="STUDENT\admin" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Вместо тривиального кода с контрактами и скриншотов решения вы бы лучше написали каким образом вы открываете клиентскую часть с серверной. Наверняка вы при этом конфиг где-то по пути теряете...

Comment: открываю как обыкновенное окно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы открываете клиентское окно как обычное окно - оно не становится клиентским процессом просто потому что лежит в другом бинарнике! Вы загрузили бинарник клиента как обычную библиотеку. А значит, конфиг-файл используется все еще серверный.

Тут у вас есть два способа.

Способ первый - добавьте серверу в конфиг настройки, которые позволят ему связаться с самим собой.

Способ второй - придумайте способ пробросить в дочернее окно прямую ссылку на сервис и вызывайте его методы без использования WCF.

Comment: тогда вопрос) что почитать что бы разобраться с первым вариантом

Comment: @DEVELOPER читайте конфиг своего же клиента - там эти настройки уже есть если вы утверждаете что при одновременном запуске все работает.

Comment: этот конфиг сам сгененрился, и откровенно говоря я не знаю что менять, я его добавил в  вопрос

Comment: @DEVELOPER вот его и добавьте в серверный конфиг. А вообще - читайте документацию, там все написано же.

Comment: спасибо!) работает, но суть того почему я использую дуплексную связь, что бы сервер отправил "всем" открытым клиентам, а он отправляет только одному, буду дальше разбираться почему так делается

Comment: сервер по задумке должен отправлять всем команду, а отправляет только тому кто вызвал ее, где может быть эта ошибка?

Comment: @DEVELOPER очевидно, ваша программа не соответствует вашей задумке. Какой отношение эта новая проблема имеет к исходному вопросу?